# Checking script caller

Tags: php, api, reference

I wrote a API for a system. It is a PHP file, which is called with some parameters. It is called like this: "https://abcdefg.de/api/api.php?test=test". This script returns sensitive data when it is called. To make sure only the right api users get the information the parameters has to contain correct credentials.

To make the api more secure the idea was to check in addition who is calling the script. For example only the website "https://test.de" should be able to call the api script. But how to achieve this in PHP? How to check what is the url of the "caller"?

I already tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` but I read that it can be easily manipulated and in our case it returns always null, because we use https instead of http.

Is there a solution to our problem?
Thanks in advance,
Filip.

Comment: Similar to what you are looking for is CORS, which is implemented by browsers to protect users. It is a mechanism where, if a request is sent to a host other than the one the page was loaded from, it will double-check first to make sure that's OK. This applies to XHR (AJAX) requests.

Comment: CORS is designed to protect users from malicious sites, not sites from malicious users. Other than an IP check (which requires to maintain a list of IPs), I don't think there're many other measures to take.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_REFERER will not be working in real with API, it's related to the form submitted from another page or website, in case this is the situation this is called cross-site request forgery, the solution here is to create a token in every rendered form and send it with the submitted data, from the backend, you will validate this token (most of the time is saved in the sessions), you can check it